# Magento transactional email shows and old template even after styling it

Tags: magento-1.7, email-templates

I made some inline styling changes on a Transactional Emails template. My changes are visible when I preview the Transactional emails template.
but the problem is when I send a test email to a gmail I still get an old version of the Transactional email template. My new changes don't show up.
I cleared the cache and I did Reindexing. but my My new Transactional email template doesn't show up.

Is there a step that i'm missing? or Is this problem related to Magento or the Server?

Comment: did you make these changes to the `System > Transactional Emails` or to the email files in `app/locale/[language]_[country]/template/email/...`?

Comment: I made the changes on System > Transactional Emails

Comment: thanks for clarifying, you can find my response in the answers :)

Comment: Did any of the answers help you out with your question?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure the emails you've edited are choosen under `System > Configuration > Sales > Sales Emails > [type of email] > [type of email] Email Template / [type of email] for guests`

Other emails like the one for welcoming a new user are spread out over the `System > Configuration`, for example under `Customer Configuration > Create New Account Options`. You'll have to locate the email templates you have updated.

By default all these dropdowns are on `[...] (Default Template From Locale)`, select your modifications name from the dropdown

Answer (score 4):

Have you assigned these templates in the system configuration for the store you're testing?

After creating a transaction email template you need to tell the store to use this for the relevant email.

So for example the New customer email is assigned in 
System Configuration -> Customers -> Customer Configuration -> Default Welcome Email

Comment: 4 minutes too slow, +1

Answer (score 0):

Inline css not works in gmail.
Gmail only supports `<style>` in the `<head>.`
Gmail does support embedded styles (`<style>)`. However, embedded styles are only supported in the head of your HTML document.

so if you added css in style in the head section it will not work.